# HighCharts navigator and range scale not working?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, highcharts

need some help. How can i limit min and max values from json array with js.

This is my problem, working on highstocks and my date is first day in unix but in array i have correct date. 
So my navigator and range scale is't working?

My json array is in variable

```
var data = <?php echo $data; ?>;
```

but i want to limit it like this

```
$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/from-sql.php?start=' + Math.round(e.min) +
                '&end=' + Math.round(e.max) + '&callback=?', function (data)
```

This is my json structure

```
[1233014400000,12.96],  
[1233100800000,13.46],  
[1233187200000,13.29],  
[1233273600000,12.88],

$(function () {

var data = <?php echo $data; ?>; // geting json array [1233014400000,12.96] //

// Create the chart
$('#container_small').highcharts('StockChart', {

    rangeSelector : {
        selected : 1,
        enabled: true
    },

    title : {
        text : 'Tankerska Next Generation d.d.'
    },

    navigator : {
        enabled: true
    },

    series : [{
        name : 'Tankerska Next Generation d.d.',
        data : data,
        marker : {
            enabled : true,
            radius : 4
        },
        shadow : true,
        tooltip : {
            valueDecimals : 2
        }
    }]
});
```

});

Thank you for help

Comment: Why don't you filter out unnecessary points in the backend? So `$data` will supply only required points?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
}
```

And the same goes with the minimum value.